# Check if iOS app is running in BG

Tags: ios, background-process

I am running the application in background via VOIP notification, I fire a special function in timer which lets me know on cloud that application is running in BG.

The problem is when I check the apps running in BG by pressing two times home button it does not show me the application is running in background.

I want to cope this issue, I want to either make visible app in BG apps or I want to know that app is in BG or in invisible memory only.

Comment: Note: I have added a log in server call now it is showing app is in background state but still not showing in the list and when I run app in BG it show same application state.

Comment: I am using 'content-available' to make a silent push call.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how do you want to check , if you just wanted to be sure that the application is running in the background you can fire a local notification, or run it on simulator, or check the debug logs.

Edit: 
this is how you check application status from code

Objective-C

```
UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
if (state == UIApplicationStateBackground)
{
   //app in background
}
```

Swift

```
 let state = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState
            if state == .Background {
                //app in background
             }
```

Comment: I want to check in code. I want to know if the app is in memory because of VOIP notification I want to kill app as it eats memory + battery but user does not know about it as it does not show in the running applications.